# Consuming .NET webservice in Java (metro) - XMLNode/XMLDocument consumption?

Tags: java, .net, xml, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I am a bit rusty in my Java, and this is my first time using metro/JAX-WS, so if this is a dumb question I apologize.

I have to write a client that consumes a .NET webservice.  I've got the basics down; I have generated the wrappers from the WSDL, and I can create my object and port and make a call and get a response.

```
    Widgets d = new Widgets();
    WidgetsSoap dp = d.getWidgetsSoap();
    ((BindingProvider)dp).getRequestContext(). put(javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://actualsite/foo.asmx");

    UserGetWidgetsResponse.UserGetWidgetsResult j = dp.userGetWidgets();
```

The webservice's return values are almost all XmlDocument or XmlNode.  How do I get from the wsimport-generated "UserGetWidgetsResponse.UserGetWidgetsResult" to the actual XML returned by the call?

I have a number of these services with a bunch of methods, so I'm hoping to find a solution that does not require modifying the generated wrappers in any way.  I also do not have control over the information returned by the web services.

Comment: Are you sure you get XmlNode and XmlDocument on the Java side? Those seem to be C# terms. This remark may seem stupid, but there are quit a lot of XML parsers around, and all behave differently :)

Comment: Well, XmlNode/XmlDocument have direct equivalents to Java's Document and Node objects.  Returning XmlNode/XmlDocuments from WS is a MS-suggested method of returning complex data.  This appears to come across correctly in the WSDL as "any" data, I'm just not sure how I pick it up on the Java side.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to get the Payload of the LocalMessage from somewhere. If you can get the LogicalMessageContext you're in business. Perhaps the dp.getRequestContext() returns one.
Can't help you further, if at all, as I normally don't generate bindings but handle the XML directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this over the weekend, but I'm not sure it's the right solution:

```
    UserGetDevicesResponse.UserGetDevicesResult j = dp.userGetDevices();
    List<Object> n = j.getContent();
    if (n.size() > 0)
    {
        Node z = (Node)n.get(0);
        System.out.println(nodeToString(z));
    }
```

This gives me the XML document response, which is what I was looking for.  I can then do whatever operations I want on the tree to extract the data I'm looking for.